# Chrome's invalid process id returned

Tags: google-chrome, visual-c++, chromium

I'm using Window's CreateProcess function to launch chrome, but intermittently the process id returned by this function doesn't exist at all. Any reference on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that when you run "chrome.exe" this actually launches several other processes (all named chrome) and the original one you called may not even be "alive" anymore. You cannot rely on this.

Comment: Is there any other way of achieving this?